# Unable to load wsgi module on Apache 2.4.9

Tags: django, apache, module, wamp, wsgi

I have python 32-bit version 2.7.9 installed on windows 8.1, and apache 2.4.9 on my wamp server. I am trying to load wsgi module. I have copied the file mod_wsgi.so in the path C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\modules. I have also edited httpd.conf and added LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so.

The error I get is :

```
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 181 of C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/conf/httpd
.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: %1 is not a valid Win32 appl
ication.
```

What am I doing wrong? Or is there something I haven't done.

Comment: You can't just randomly copy libraries around. A `.so` file is a Linux shared library; you almost certainly need a DLL. You will need to install the correct one for your version of Windows and your architecture.

Comment: I checked it. I have installed the correct one.

Comment: Where did you get the mod_wsgi binary from and is it the correct architecture and compiler variant for your Apache? Have you read very carefully https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/blob/develop/win32/README.rst

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error once when i had cgi module and tried to load the wsgi module , and the thing is i did not enable cgi so it comes enabled out of the box so just disable it and try to restart wamp